# Background fixed with regard to viewport, but also scrolling

Tags: css

In a `<section>`, I have a background-image with a fixed position, like this:

```
  section {
    background: url("/images/bergen_background.png"), rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background-blend-mode: color-dodge;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

What I want is to have it scroll when it has reached the end of the `<section>`, and I've been able to add the JS logic to add a CSS class, `section.bottom`, which will remove the `fixed` property for the background.

However, when I remove the `fixed` property and scroll down, the `background-size: cover` seem to break and the background-image seem to not fit the entire image in the viewport.

```
  section.bottom {
    /* what do I add here? */
  }
```

What do I do to have a background-image not-scroll and then scroll while having the background-image be fixed with regard to the viewport?

*First image is before scroll reached end of the element, second is after scroll has reached the end of the element*

[image: first image is fixed and the second image removed the fixed]

Reproduced here:
https://svelte.dev/repl/04b96435904e4625a3ddbcc28bd7054f?version=3.38.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I have fixed your problem but not sure.

I just thinking about idea which might solve the problem my idea like below :

First : remove `background-size: cover;` and add

```
background: url(<image>) center top no-repeat fixed;
background-size: auto <width size in %>; /*Beacause background-size: cover; 
creates the scrolling issue.*/
```

Second : with the logic JS you can change `background-attachment: fixed;` into     `background-attachment: scroll;`.

I think now everything is good.

Comment: Okey, disregard what I wrote above. Seems like it works! Thanks!

Comment: @Grotle Glad to help :)